# Always Display Table Header, while all rows are display:hidden;

Tags: html, css

I have a dynamic table, and depending on user events, the table's number of rows change. My `tr` not of class `.selected` are set to `display:none;` -- and it's perfectly possible that no table row has that class. The issue is the table header disappears, when I set `display:none` except for when the original first row has class `selected`. In other words, only when the first row is selected does the header appear. That makes sense I guess, but is there any way around this when working with `display:none;`? I would like the table header to always be visible, no matter which rows are hidden.

```
tr:not(.selected) {
    display:none;
}
```

I tried adding things like `not(:first-child)` but none worked. And am I on the right track using this approach? I figured dynamically adding and removing rows would involve too much iteration or slow things down.

Comment: tr:not(.selected), remove ':' after not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the colon after your `not` isn't needed, so remove it:

```
tr:not(.selected) {
  display: none;
}
```

As for hiding only data rows (as opposed to header rows) that don't have the `.selected` class, there are a few ways of accomplishing this. What I'd recommend is splitting your table using `<thead>` and `<tbody>`:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Heading 1
      </th>
      <th>
        Heading 2
      </th>
      <th>
        ....
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <!-- your data here -->
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then you can use the following CSS to ensure that only rows in the table's body - not its header - disappear without the `.selected` class:

```
tbody tr:not(.selected) {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Yea, I dont know why I hit the colon button so many times, thank you for pointing out that syntax error. Your answer worked great, nice and short too!